# How to optimize query in Oracle with timestamp condition?

Tags: oracle, optimization, timestamp

How can I optimize the following query?

```
DELETE FROM table_a a 
WHERE date < systimestamp 
   OR a.column_name NOT IN (SELECT b.column_name FROM table_b b);
```

The problem is in the condition "date < systimestamp". Is being spent around 11 seconds to execute the query due to this condition.

For information, table_a has 12073 rows and table_b has 37289 rows. The column "date" has timestamp type, for example, a value of this column would be 31/12/20 23:59:59,000000000.

Comment: I would say, if anything slow that would be your table b subquery.

Comment: Show us the execution plan. Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: Try This:

DELETE FROM table_a a WHERE date < systimestamp OR a.column_name NOT in 
(SELECT b.column_name FROM table_b b inner join table_a c on b.column_name = c.column_name);

Comment: If I make the query only part "DELETE FROM table_a a 
WHERE date < systimestamp", the time spent is still the 11 seconds. Then the problem is in this comparison. Names used here for the tables and columns are fictitious, do not care about them.

Comment: Follows the execution plan of the query.

-----------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name           | Cost (%CPU)|
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT    |                |    25   (4)|
|   1 |  DELETE             | TABLE_A        |            |
|*  2 |   FILTER            |                |            |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_A        |    25   (4)|
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_B        |    96   (0)|
-----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Consider your query.  The optimizer cannot effectively use an index to eliminate data from qualification.  Full table scans are to be expected.